# Install and import site-packages for Python 2 and 3 on Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I installed `brew` and then

```
brew install python
brew install python3
```

Install `flask` with `pip`

```
pip install flask
```

Try

```
python -c 'import flask'
```

But I got exception

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Set and export `PYTHONPATH`

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So far so good. But when I tried to install a package with `pip3` for Python 3, I got error message

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: ":/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

How to use site-packages without the `PYTHONPATH` trick to make both `pip` and `pip3` usable and both Python 2 and Python 3 able to import site-packages?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with brew but if you type `python (anything)` at the system prompt I would expect that to run the built-in system Python - is that the same Python installation into which you've installed the flask module?

Answer (score 5):

You should consider install [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) for this.

> **pyenv** lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python. It's simple, unobtrusive, and follows the UNIX tradition of single-purpose tools that do one thing well.

To install, just type:

```
$ brew install pyenv
```

Add this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Once installed use `pyenv` to install python versions you need:

```
$ pyenv install -l/--list --> List all available versions
$ pyenv install 2.7.6
$ pyenv install 3.3.3
```

Run this command after you install a python version:

```
$ pyenv rehash
```

You can specify multiple versions via `PYENV_VERSION` at once. Let's say if you have two versions of 2.7.6 and 3.3.3. If you prefer 2.7.6 over 3.3.3,

```
$ pyenv shell 2.7.6 3.3.3
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.6 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
* 3.3.3 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3.3 --version
Python 3.3.3
```

Comment: I installed `pyenv`. Could you please give some examples of how to use it to solve my problem?

Comment: Update my answer.

Comment: Better use virtualenv which is now part of python

Comment: @Mark virtualenv only creates isolated virtual environments based on existing Python interpreter installations.  pyenv installs (and manages) new Python interpreters and environments, and can additionally wrap virtualenv or venv to manage virtual environments in a consistent manner.  pyenv has no dependency on Python itself, and can be used to bootstrap a Python environment on a “clean” machine.

Answer (score 4):

To use both *Python 2* and *Python 3* on OS X, one should avoid using the Mac pre-installed *python*.

1. Install *python* with *homebrew*:

   ```
   brew install python
   brew install python3
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/paths`:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/bin
   /bin
   /usr/local/sbin
   /usr/sbin
   /sbin
   ```

Make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`. The former is use by *homebrew* and the latter is where the Mac pre-installed *python* executable lives. Show your `PATH` for a double check:

```
    $ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Now I can install packages with *pip2* and *pip3* for 2 versions of Python separately.

Comment: My `/etc/paths` looks like you describe. Your answer did not work for me.

Comment: @n1000 `echo $PATH; echo $PYTHONPATH`. What do you get?